# Pause execution of program from callback function

Tags: ros, c++, rostime

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my main, I have defined a callback function with the following code:

```
// initialize a Subscribing for reading the current pose
CallbackHandler cb_handler(slam, &node_list, &node_tstamps);
ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("/pose2D", 1000, &CallbackHandler::checkOdometricConstraint, &cb_handler);
```

After that I call `ros::spin()` to wait for callbacks

```
ros::spin();
```

Is it possible to pause the system execution from within the callback function?
I tried using cpp approaches like `system("pause")` or `std::cin.get()` but that didn't work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231733/pause-execution-of-program-from-callback-function/) by [bergercookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25299/bergercookie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 257 on 2016-04-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-12**:
can you tell us why you want to do that (just trying to avoid an xy-problem)?

**Comment by [bergercookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25299/bergercookie/) on 2016-04-12**:
I incrementally add elements to an std::vector when the callback function is called, and each time this happens I need some time to investigate the added element. I could use ros::Duration(x).sleep() for this purpose but it would be handier if I could pause execution as long as I needed..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-12**:
With "I need some time to investigate" are you really talking about you, the person, or the rest of your program?

**Comment by [bergercookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25299/bergercookie/) on 2016-04-12**:
I am talking about me watching the program output. My goal is to see what is the output of the program, for debugging reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. You could pause outside of a callback, if you really need to; store the value you will add to the vector in the callback.
2. By using simulation time you can make your clock server pause, just like you pause a ROS bag from being played.

---

For debugging reasons (this one is a clear case of this, from your comments) you should really use a debugger, not print the contents of a vector. You will be glad you did it if you put some time into it. Super easy if you have an IDE (for gdb see [this](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB)).

First of all start [here](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs). If you find yourself really needing to use a launch file, such that you can't run your node from the IDE, maybe your IDE provides a way to **attach** the debugger to the already running node.

---

Originally posted by [dotcom](https://answers.ros.org/users/19883/dotcom/) with karma: 120 on 2018-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0